# Global variables in Snakemake rules

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm creating a simple snakemake pipeline that contains global variables in the Snakefile. What's the recommended way to use these global variables in the Python scripts called in my rules?

I'm currently using argparse command line arguments as described here ([Snakemake: pass command line arguments to scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370077/snakemake-pass-command-line-arguments-to-scripts)) but am wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Have you read [the docs on external scripts and accessing variables](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#python)?

Comment: @merv Thanks for your response. I have seen those but I think it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm specifically trying to use variables defined at the top of my Snakefile (outside of rules and outside of the config file) that are not input, output, or config values. Perhaps argparse is the only way.

Answer (score 8):

## Passing Variables

If the variable is specified in the Snakefile, then it could be passed via `params`. For example,

**Snakefile**

```python
# global variable to use
FOO = 100

rule test:
  input: "a.in"
  output: "a.out"
  params:
    foo=FOO  # pass the variable value as 'foo'
  script: "scripts/test.py"
```

**scripts/test.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

# access the variable through the `snakemake` object
print(snakemake.params.foo)
```

See [Snakemake documentation on external Python scripts](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#python).

---

## Additional Comments

Note, that generally I find it better practice to place a variable like the above example in a `config.yaml` instead. That helps centralize adjustable parameters, providing a single point of configuration for reuse. Despite the availability of `snakemake.config` in external scripts, I still prefer to explicitly pass configuration values as `params`, so as to make it clear which rules depend on what configuration values.

#### Example

**config.yaml**

```yaml
foo: 100
```

**Snakefile**

```python
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule test:
  input: "a.in"
  output: "a.out"
  params:
    foo=config["foo"] 
  script: "scripts/test.py"
```

**scripts/test.py**

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

# access the variable through the `snakemake` object
print(snakemake.params.foo)
```

#### Overriding Configuration Parameters

If the value is provided in the `config.yaml`, one can also then (optionally) override it at the CLI:

```bash
snakemake --config foo=150
```

See [documentation on configuration parameters](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#standard-configuration).

Comment: Thank you, this makes perfect sense! Is there a way to make these config values optional in the command line?

Comment: @amm I added a note to the answer re: CLI overrides

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation. I find that I get a KeyError when I have a default value in the `config.yaml` (i.e. `comp_het="None"`) but I don't specify it in the command line (snakemake -c1. --config id=1 genome_build="hg19"). I'd like it to be that config values are optional in the command line so that I don't have to include `comp_het` when I'm not changing the default value.

Comment: @amm are you using YAML syntax? I.e., `comp_het="None"` is invalid - should be `comp_het: "None"` in the YAML.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. In the YAML file, I have `comp_het: "None"` and in the command line, it would be `--config comp_het="None"`.

Comment: Still, it sounds like your `config.yaml` is not being loaded correctly. Run it through a linter to make sure the YAML is valid (note that YAML has some whitespace sensitivity). Also, you added the `configfile: "config.yaml"` at the top of the Snakefile? Not sure what else would lead it to fail to load the config file values.

Comment: Aha! I had ```config: "config.yaml"``` at the top of my Snakefile, rather than ```configfile: "config.yaml"```. Thanks so much.